# Dataframe has an empty cell, how to replace with 0?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is sourced from an excel CSV file. because of how I build the source file, some of the columns will come in with blanks (i.e. I didnt put anything in that cell in excel). I need to set those cells to 0 before I process the data.

I read the data in using fread.

Some of the cells have come in with N/A in the value which is easy enough to replace. However some show "blank" in View(theDataFrame) and are not caught by replace_na. I cant figure out what is in these cells so i can target them and replace with 0.

I tried `paste("*", theDataFrame[1, "Current Price"], "*")` which printed an asterisk, two white spaces and another asterisk. so, I tried `` gsub("/s/s", "0", theDataFrame$`Current Price`) `` but that did not work.

`is.empty(theDataFrame[1, "Current Price"])` is `FALSE` so, it's not empty. How can i figure out what the heck `fread` put in there so I can replace it?

Thanks!

Comment: For clarity, often it's not what `fread` put in there so much as what Excel put in there and caused either ambiguity or clearly something (that you did not expect).

Comment: @akrun, care to explain why you rolled back my edit?

Comment: @r2evans I thought the OP's post was using `paste(""` instead of `paste("*"`.  When you edited, I find it as `paste("*"`. not sure if that is what OP intended

Comment: In order to see what the unedited question showed, you can just ***view*** the edit history, you don't have to change it, but you already knew that.

Comment: @r2evans yes, i did check that and it was not clear.  Anyway, rollbacked to your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
theDataFrame[theDataFrame == ''] <- 0
```